# jQuery Show/Hide Text When Clicking Images

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have three images that act as buttons. Each one has the same class. When I click an image, I want the text, "Active" to appear below it (outside the div the image is in). It would be the same text under each image but if I click another image, I want the text to hide where it had been showing and show under the image I just clicked. Right now, I click a picture, "Active" appears under all three images, I click again, all three disappear. Where am I going wrong?

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
    {
        $('p.active').hide();
    });

$(function()
    {
        $('.mosaic-block').click(function(){
            $('.mosaic-block').removeClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
            $(this).addClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
            $('p.active').show(showHide);
        });
    });

function showHide()
    {
        var id=$(this).attr("p");

        if($(this).is(":visible"))
        {
          $(id).hide();
          $(this).html("");
        }
        else
        {
          $(id).show();
          $(this).html("ACTIVE");
        }
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="imgBlock">
 <div class="mosaic-block cover">
   <div class="mosaic-overlay" style="display: block; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
     <img type="image" src="/images/g_crop.jpg"/>
   </div>
       <a href="javascript:;" onclick="launchX3()" id="x3" class="mosaic-backdrop" style="display:inline;">
     <div class="details">
       <h1>G Demo</h1>
           <h4>Select G</h4>
     </div>
       </a>
</div>
   <img class="button" type="image" src="/images/g_btn.jpg"/>
   <p class="active">ACTIVE</p>
</div>

<div class="imgBlock">
  <div class="mosaic-block cover">
<div class="mosaic-overlay" style="display: block; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
      <img type="image" src="/images/e_crop.jpg"/>
</div>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="launchX2()" id="x2" class="mosaic-backdrop" style="display:inline;">
  <div class="details">                
    <h1>E Demo</h1>
    <h4>Select E</h4>
      </div>
</a>
  </div>
  <img class="button" type="image" src="/images/e_btn.jpg"/>
  <p class="active">ACTIVE</p>
</div>

<div class="imgBlock">
  <div class="mosaic-block cover boxgridLast">
 <div class="mosaic-overlay" style="display: block; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
   <img type="image" src="/images/c_crop.jpg"/>
 </div>
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="launchX1()" id="x1" class="mosaic-backdrop" style="display:inline;">
 <div class="details">
   <h1>C Demo</h1>
   <h4>Select C</h4>
 </div>
 </a>
 </div>
     <img class="button" type="image" src="/images/c_btn.jpg"/>
     <p class="active">ACTIVE</p>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply over complicating things.

This should do the job

```
$(function () {
    $('p.active').hide();

    $('.mosaic-block').click(function () {
        var $this =$(this);
        $('.mosaic-block').removeClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
        $this.addClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
        $('p.active').hide();
        // traverse to the closest `imgBlock` class and 
        //  find the p.active element and show it
        $this.closest('.imgBlock').find('p.active').show();

    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/pQLhy/2/)**

Comment: This worked like a charm. It's easy to over complicate things when I spin my wheels trying to figure it out. This is much simpler than what I had. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a couple of things, but I think it could be simplified a lot. What you essentially want to do is first hide all the "active" elements, and then show the element in the block you've just clicked. To do this, you could do the following:

```
$(function()
    {
        $('.mosaic-block').click(function(){
            $('.mosaic-block').removeClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
            $(this).addClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
            $('p.active').hide();
            $(this).find('p.active').show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/hsrQb/)***

The other solutions don't seem to toggle properly. If you want your active to toggle on click, and to toggle when clicked in another area to that area, you should use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) coupled with a [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to prevent incorrect hiding.

```
$('p.active').hide();
$('.mosaic-block').click(function(){
 $('.mosaic-block').removeClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
 $(this).addClass('mosaic-block-highlighted');
 var $thisActive = $(this.parentNode).find('.active');
 $('p.active').not($thisActive).hide();
 $thisActive.toggle();
});
```